# Cygwin and aliases

Tags: cygwin

I have cygwin installed on win7. I have successfully moved my homedir to another directory (by changinge /etc/passwd).

Now I am trying to add some aliases. I have created a .bash_aliases file and activated in .bashrc. But now here is my problem:

I have added the following line:

```
alias la="ls -la"
```

After a restart of the terminal, I tried to run 'la' and I get the following error:

```
$ la
ls: unknown option --
```

Now I tried only for testing:

```
alias lx="ls"
```

and afterwards I get:

```
$ lx
-bash: $'ls\r': unknown command
```

I also tried to add "/bin/" in front of the commands, but it doesn't change anything. If I try to call "ls" or "ls -la" in the terminal, I get the expected result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following things:

1. Cover your alais with single quotes `alias la='ls -la'`
2. run `dos2unix` command on all files your are editing i.e `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases` . Because it seems your files are having special characters.

Comment: Thank you! dos2unix helped! I created the files with notepad++ under windows. Now I will only use nano or something else for those kind of things :)