# How can I make “gradle --console=rich” the default?

Tags: gradle

Along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977196/how-can-i-make-gradle-stacktrace-the-default#29983737) (which works for me, BTW) and the [javadocs](https://docs.gradle.org/3.2.1/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#setConsoleOutput%28org.gradle.api.logging.configuration.ConsoleOutput%29), I tried

```
gradle.startParameter.consoleOutput = org.gradle.api.logging.configuration.ConsoleOutput.Rich
```

in my `~/.gradle/init.gradle`. However, I still need `--console=rich` to get color output. Why?

Tested with Gradle 2.14.1 and 3.2.1.

Terminal is cygwin urxvt with TERM variable set to rxvt-unicode-256color.

Comment: [Please see this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55859188/935148)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not interested in an Eclipse solution. And I am now using cygwin mintty and gradle 5.2, and it defaults to the rich console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you can force the rich console from a gradle script, as the detection happens likely before the script is interpreted.

[NativeServices class](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/native/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/nativeintegration/services/NativeServices.java) provides the integration with the console. If you look at the source code, there are two messages possibly printed in log:

`Native-platform terminal integration is not available. Continuing with fallback.`

`Unable to load from native-platform backed ConsoleDetector. Continuing with fallback.`

The latter might give you more information why. Try running the gradle script with `--debug`. You will likely find out that you are missing a native library that is either not available in cygwin or it is, but is not on library path.

I believe it works when you specify the rich console from the command line, because gradle forces the colours even though the console doesn't indicate it supports them.

Does it work if you don't use the cygwin console in Windows native command line or maybe GitBash?

There is a workaround how you can make this work. [You can create an alias in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206666/cygwin-and-aliases) that will always add the `--console=rich`.

If you are using gradle wrapper, you can edit the `gradlew` script and add the command line parameter. To make it automated, you can change the `wrapper` task to alter your script in the `doLast` part.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I get these messages from NativeServices: `Initialized native services in: C:\home\strebcri\.gradle\native`, `Native-platform posix files is not available.  Continuing with fallback.`

Comment: Same in the windows console, which uses colors by default anyway. With Windows console, my init setting is ignored too, i.e. it stays colored when I change `init.gradle` to `Plain`. Git bash: default colored, init setting `Plain` ignored, too. Setting `TERM` to `cygwin` (as in Git bash) does not help in cygwin urxvt. I as a lone cygwin user don't like to edit the team's gradlew for this.

Comment: @EndlosSchleife as I said, I don't think that setting changes anything as it happens after the console is initialized. `Native-platform posix files is not available` just points out you are in cygwin and not in a native Unix/Linux system.

Comment: OK, this is the answer to accept then, it seems. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Since [Gradle 4.3](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases/tag/v4.3.0) you can use `org.gradle.console` property in `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.console=rich
```

> A new console verbose mode will print outcomes of all tasks (like `UP-TO-DATE`) like Gradle 3.5 and earlier did. You can set this via `--console=verbose` or by a new Gradle property `org.gradle.console=(plain rich verbose)`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a file called `gradle.properties` inside your `~/.gradle/` folder.
2. Inside `gradle.properties`, add the line `org.gradle.console=rich`.

Each builds will run under `--console=rich` automatically because the new `gradle.properties` will be merged with the `gradle.properties` of your project.

If your project's `gradle.properties` contains the same tag as the local file, your project's will be used overriding the local file's

Comment: Thanks. But nowerdays, gradle treats [mintty as a rich](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/8189) by default. The problem instead is that it messes it up, but with this [workaround](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8204#issuecomment-644232747), everything seems to be okay. At least I didn't miss ConPTY support (yet).

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux/Mac set

```
alias gradle='gradle --console rich'
```

in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: That will work, but feels like a workaround. The real question is why is the console on Linux not detected properly, and how can Gradle be fixed to support color on Linux by default?

Answer (score 3):

In **Gradle Wrapper**, add the following line:

```
org.gradle.console=rich
```

to `./gradle.properties` in the root folder, where the `gradlew` script is located.